# Access Denied messgaes in Process Monitor

Tags: internet-explorer, permission-denied, process-monitor

I have an application that runs on a web server under a local user that resides in the Power User group.  Process monitor is reporting the following Access Denied Errors:

User: Network Service, All Access Denied on HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters

User: Local User Power User Account, Read/Write Access Denied on HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap

When I remove the user from the Power Users group and add it to the Admin Group, the error does not occur and the program runs as expected.

My research has shown that others solve this issue by simply giving the needed access on the registry keys, but I'm thinking that is has something to do with IE 8 security settings, although all I have seen about this relates to DEP which does not seem to be installed.

The local user cannot be in the admin group in production so I need to solve its issues for his current authority level.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: test by comparing which addons are loaded on each account. Tools>Manage Addons>Show>Currently loaded addons.
or test the Power user account in noAddons mode.
It would appear that an addon is trying to add/remove domains to the IE security zones.